# Removing instances in weka to normalize result classes

Tags: weka, filter

Trying construct a classifier, however one class is highly overrepresented.

I have tried weighting, but the data set is large and I need to sub sample it. 
So I thought I might be able to remove some instances from the overrepresented class instead.

Is there any filters I could use to remove a subset of only one of the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at SpreadSubsample filter in supervised instance filters. It should do the job. Good luck.